# Calling AlarmManager based on date & time

Tags: java, android, date, alarmmanager

I was having some trouble when trying to set the alarm manager to run at specific time if it meets the condition. For this part of the codes, I am checking if the event date was one day before the current date:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String currentDate = dateFormat.format(new Date());
for (int count = 0; count < _eventlist.size(); count++) {

        Date alarmDate = null;
        try {
            alarmDate = dateFormat.parse(_eventlist.get(count)
                    .getEventDate());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(alarmDate);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        Date alarmBeforeOneDay = calendar.getTime();
        Log.i("Alarm", dateFormat.format(alarmBeforeOneDay));
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

        if (dateFormat.format(alarmBeforeOneDay).equals(currentDate)) {
            if (!AlarmInitialized(context)) {
                scheduleAlarms(context);
            }
        }
    }
```

And it meets the condition, it will execute the scheduleAlarms() to send push notification:

```
public static void scheduleAlarms(Context context) {
/*  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    long firstRunTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();*/
    Log.i("Schedule","Alarm");
    Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());//set the current time and date for this calendar

    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));

    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    notificationCount = notificationCount + 1;

    notificationIntent.putExtra("NotifyCount", notificationCount);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);

    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

BootReceiver.class:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {
    if (i.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        ProfileUpcomingEvent.scheduleAlarms(context);
    }
}
```

Alarm.class:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1,
                new Intent(), 0);
        notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                "Notification", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Event Reminder",
                "Registered event at WHERE is tomorrow!",
                contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(
                Integer.parseInt(intent.getExtras().get("NotifyCount")
                        .toString()), notification);
        ProfileUpcomingEvent.updateAlarmLastRun(context);
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<receiver android:name=".Alarm" >
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

So in this method, I tried to set it to run at 00:30 if it meets the condition. However, let's say I set the eventDate to 26/11/2014. It supposed to send me a push-notification by 25/11/2014 00:30 which is one day before the eventDate but it does not. I wonder why it wont run as I've checked the date format by using Log and it was correct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it going in `scheduleAlarms` ?

Comment: are you just concerned with data or DATE + mili seconds ??

Comment: If you are trying to match TIME also then you must have same time i.e. *00:30* in *currentDate*

Comment: But I thought I was comparing the currentDate (25/11/2014) to compare with eventDate (26/11/2014). If it's one day before, then I proceed to scheduleAlarm()?

Comment: But is it really calling `scheduleAlarm`?? it depends on your dateFormat actually..post full code

Comment: @SweetWisherツ I've updated the question already. I don't think it's calling scheduleAlarm() otherwise, I would have received a push notification.

Comment: Then debug why it is not calling.. You might be going in if block but what about `AlarmInitialized` ??

Comment: I tried to debug but I still don't understand why is it not working and that's why I am posting a thread here :) What do you mean by AlarmInitialized?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65670/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-i-was-so-lost).

Comment: It's not working yet. Any guides?